# Problem about primitive root

Tags: cryptography

Let p be a prime such that $q = \frac{p − 1}{2}$  is also prime. Suppose that g is an
integer satisfying

$g \not\equiv \pm 1 \pmod p$ and $g^q \not\equiv 1 \pmod p$.

Prove that g is a primitive root modulo p.

Comment: If $g^q\not\equiv1~(p)$ then the order of $g$ does not divide $q$. But the order of every unit mod $p$ divides $\phi(p)=p-1=2q$. So $g$'s order divides $2q$ but not $q$...

Comment: This appears to be Q1.33 from p.54 of [An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-77993-5), by J.H. Silverman, Jill Pipher and Jeffrey Hoffstein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** The order of $g$ divides $p-1$. But since $(p-1)/2$ is prime, $p-1$ has very few divisors!  And we are told that $g^q\not\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, which rules out one of them as the order of $g$. You can decide why $2$ and $1$ are ruled out.